# Date formation in viewmanager php

Tags: php, mysql, date, datetime, format

i'm very new to this Forum. I'm working on my own website and got a problem.
Because i'm very new to coding and not very skilled with php i can't find a solution for this little problem.
I would like to formate my date from the Database to a "friendlydate" 
e.g. Date from Database: 2016-06-08 00:00:00
my wish-date: 08.06.2016
Here is my Code from the viewmanager, where i want do define the 
"friendlydate"

```
// assign values to view object
    $viewBlog->id = $value->id;
    $viewBlog->bild = $value->bild;
    $viewBlog->date = $value->date;
    $viewBlog->author = $value->author;
    $viewBlog->title = $value->title;
    $viewBlog->text = $value->text;
    $viewBlog->category_id = $value->category_id;
    if (strlen($value->text) > 280) {$viewBlog->shorttext = substr($value->text,0,280)."...";} else {$viewBlog->shorttext = $value->text;}
    ***$viewBlog->friendlydate = here is my problem;***
    $viewBlog->objCategory = $this->getViewCategory($value->category_id);
```

Comment: How can the original date be accessed? Something like `$value->date`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can *parse* your original date in to a `DateTime` object which will then allow you to format the date however you like. For instance:

```
$date = new DateTime($value->wish-date);
$viewBlog->friendlydate = $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

In this case, `friendlydate` would be `2016-06-08 00:00:00`. To see how to specify what format you like [see the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php).

Comment: Thank you very much! your answer solved my problem and helped me understand my case!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `$viewBlog->friendlydate` is your date variable,
`$viewBlog->friendlydate = date("m.d.Y");`
where m is numeric representation of a month, with leading zeros, n is numeric representation of a month without leading zeros and Y is a full numeric representation of a year output as 4 digits.

Answer (score 0):

Using string functions:

```
$parts = explode('-', substr('2016-06-08 00:00:00', 0, 10));
$date = $parts[2].'.'.$parts[1].'.'.$parts[0];
```

This will convert the string as you have described. You may also want to look into [PHP date functions](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php).

Answer (score 0):

You will just need to reformat your date. I am really fond of the `DateTime` method in php.

```
// Get the current date with its format
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $value->date);

// Convert it to a new format
$viewBlog->date = $date->format('d.m.Y');
```

In the resource below you can find information about different formats in which you can output your date.

#### Resources

- [DateTime - Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php)